# What is the reason I am unable to use the update method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

The update method seems to not work and I get the error below:

```
Started PATCH "/lessons/4" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-07-20 11:23:27 +0900
Processing by LessonsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+95AUkvSbAUfVzAp9xweeiuq8IKq3gdqJB5oP8HoRP3NvkoYHkGRYe1TQSMxVtTZGPlATx6ltb0SThD6ifMXpg==", "lesson"=>{"title"=>"まずはじめに", "content"=>"Jelly beans chupa chups soufflé toffee cookie croissant sugar plum cookie. Danish caramels gummi bears marzipan apple pie cupcake jelly pudding dragée. Jelly-o pastry halvah sweet. Pudding jujubes marshmallow pie soufflé. Tart chocolate bar dragée bonbon cotton candy jelly beans chupa chups. Cheesecake tart chupa chups candy canes sweet roll biscuit candy lollipop. Chupa chups lemon drops chocolate bear claw muffin tiramisu pastry marzipan ice cream. Sweet candy canes danish halvah caramels cupcake donut lemon drops gummi bears."}, "commit"=>"更新", "id"=>"4"}
  Lesson Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "lessons".* FROM "lessons" WHERE "lessons"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for LessonsController#update, rendering head :no_content
Completed 204 No Content in 112ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

I have a Course model and a Lesson model and I am able to use the update method for my Course model but not for the Lesson model...

Any suggestions?

Comment: please upload LessonController,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me and hopefully, it must do for you too if it's saved in DB

```
def update
 @lesson = Lesson.find(params[:id])
 if @lesson.update(params)
   redirect_to root_path, alert: "Your lesson is saved!"
 else
   render 'edit', alert: "Oops! There was a problem, please try again"
 end
end
```